# Salariedemployee employee

Tags: java

Hey guys first time being here. I am beginning to learn Java and for one of our first assignments is to:

Suppose we want to determine the best paid employee in a file of full-time, salaried, company employees. For a salaried employee, each line in the file consists of the name, salary and an optional bonus. The gross pay is the salary plus bonus, if a bonus is given;  0 indicates that there is no bonus. For example, suppose the file "salaried.txt" contains the following:

```
Agrawal,Harsh 450.00  0

Chiger,Steve  420.00 60.00

Cromer,Jason  460.00  0

Petkov,Yuli   430.00 40.00

Siddiqi,Amena 460.00 15.00
```

Then the best-paid salaried employee is Chiger, Steve with a gross pay of $480.00

Everytime I try to run the program, It does not read the name of the file. I do not know if I am missing something in either SalariedEmployee or SalariedCompany but the code I have is the following. I am basically stuck.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class SalariedEmployee extends FullTimeEmployee 
{
     protected double grossPay,    
                 bonus,
                 salary;

public SalariedEmployee()
{
    grossPay=0.00;
    bonus=0.00;  
    salary=0.00;
}
public SalariedEmployee (String name, double salary, double bonus) 
{        
    this.name = name;
    this.salary=salary;
    this.bonus=bonus;
    if (bonus==0)
    {
        grossPay+=salary;
    }
    else 
    {
        grossPay=salary+bonus;
    }
}
public boolean setSalaryPay(double income)
{
    if(income<0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    this.salary=income;
    return true;
}
public double getSalary()
{
         return salary;
         }
public double getBonus()
{
    return bonus;
}
public String toString()
{       
    final String FULL_TIME_STATUS = "FULL TIME SALARIED";
    return super.toString() + FULL_TIME_STATUS;
} // meth

}


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

 public class SalariedCompany extends Company
 {
public static void main (String[ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    new SalariedCompany().run();
} 
protected SalariedEmployee getNextEmployee (Scanner sc)
{
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner (sc.nextLine());

    String name = lineScanner.next();       

    double salary = lineScanner.nextDouble();        

    double bonus = lineScanner.nextDouble();  

    return new SalariedEmployee (name, salary, bonus);
} // method getNextEmployee     

} // class HourlyCompany
```

SalariedEmployee and SalariedCompany are the files I need to turn in for my homework.
the rest of the files to know what the classes above are taking about are:

```
 public class FullTimeEmployee implements Employee
 {   
protected /*private*/ String name;

protected /*private*/ double grossPay; 
public FullTimeEmployee()
{
     final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

     name = EMPTY_STRING;
     grossPay = 0.00;
} 
public FullTimeEmployee (String name, double grossPay)
{  
    this.name = name;
    this.grossPay = grossPay;         
} // 2-parameter constructor

public String getName()
{
    return name;
} // method getName


public double getGrossPay()
{
    return grossPay;
} // method getGrossPay



public String toString()
{       
   final String EMPLOYMENT_STATUS = " FULL TIME";

     return name + MONEY.format (grossPay) + EMPLOYMENT_STATUS; 
     // the format method returns a String representation of grossPay.   
} // method toString

 } // class FullTimeE

import java.util.*; // for the Scanner class

import java.io.*;  // for the FileNotFoundException class � see Section 2.3

 public class Company
 {       

public static void main (String[ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    new Company().run();
} // method main

/**
 *  Determines and prints out the best paid of the full-time employees 
 *  scanned in from a specified file. 
 *
 */  
public void run() throws FileNotFoundException  // see Section 2.3            
{
    final String INPUT_PROMPT = "Please enter the path for the file of employees: ";

    final String BEST_PAID_MESSAGE = 
     "\n\nThe best-paid employee (and gross pay) is ";

   final String NO_INPUT_MESSAGE = 
    "\n\nError: There were no employees scanned in.";

   String fileName;

   System.out.print (INPUT_PROMPT);
   fileName = new Scanner (System.in).nextLine();
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File (fileName));

   FullTimeEmployee bestPaid = findBestPaid (sc);

   if (bestPaid == null)
       System.out.println (NO_INPUT_MESSAGE);
   else
       System.out.println (BEST_PAID_MESSAGE + bestPaid.toString());
} // method run


/**
 *  Returns the best paid of all the full-time employees scanned in. 
 *  
 *  @param sc � the Scanner object used to scan in the employees.
 *
 *  @return the best paid of all the full-time employees scanned in,
 *                 or null there were no employees scanned in.
 *
 */  
public FullTimeEmployee findBestPaid (Scanner sc)
{
    FullTimeEmployee full, 
                     bestPaid = new FullTimeEmployee();                            

    while (sc.hasNext())
    {                               
         full = getNextEmployee (sc);           
         if (full.getGrossPay() > bestPaid.getGrossPay())
            bestPaid = full; 
    } //while   
    if (bestPaid.getGrossPay() == 0.00)    
      return null;
    return bestPaid;
} // method findBestPaid



     protected /*private*/ FullTimeEmployee getNextEmployee (Scanner sc)
     {
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner (sc.nextLine());

        String name = lineScanner.next();

        double grossPay = lineScanner.nextDouble();

        return new FullTimeEmployee (name, grossPay);
     } // method getNextEmployee

 } // class Company




import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

public interface Employee
{

    final static DecimalFormat MONEY = new DecimalFormat (" $0.00");
    String getName();

    double getGrossPay();

    String toString();

 } // interface Employee
```

Thanks again you guys in advance.

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Have you narrowed down at all where the error might be occurring? I'd recommend [paring this down to as little code as possible while still reproducing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
fileName = new Scanner (System.in).nextLine();
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
```

... you taking file name from user. Basic possibility for errors is in which form file path is given. Try to modify the code:

```
fileName = new Scanner (System.in).nextLine();
File file = new File (fileName);
// print actual file absolute path
System.out.printf("File absolute path: %s", file.getAbsolutePath());

Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);
```

Run the app as you usually do, and see the output of actual absolute file path. If it's not matched yours expectation (like, you typing `salaries.txt` and it gives you `C:\Users\user\...\folder-with-app\dist\salaries.txt`), then it means, you pointing your's app at the different `salaries.txt` file.

If that's the case, try to input absolute path to real `salaries.txt` file, or move it to folder, specified in `File absolute path:`-s output.